# permission to write/system/etc on android 4.3

Tags: android

Hi I have an HTC ONE rooted. I would like to modify a file in the /system/etc folder, but even if I mount through the terminal the file system in write mode, when I try to modify something with my editor, it says "only read file system".

The command I used is 
"mount -o rw, remount -t rootfs /system"

Any suggestion? Android version is 4.3

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the permission if you are not allowed.

```
chmod 777 file_path
```

It will give permission to read/write/execute to all the users,group,other

### Update

Before this do execute the below commands

```
adb shell
su 
mount -o rw,remount rootfs /
```

Comment: I wrote in the terminal

chmod 777 /system/etc

and it returns the following :

"unable to chmod /system/etc: Read-only file system"

Comment: I've executed the commands you wrote, appearently without any issue. Then I tried to modify the file through ES File Explorer, but I still can't...

Comment: @user3378172 Lastly did you execute `chmod 777 file_path`, Make sure you are giving correct file path

Comment: yes, I executed the following "chmod 777 /system/etc"

Comment: I also tried to create a new empty file in the same folder with Root Browser. It seems to be able to create it, but after rebooting the device it desappears..so I guess I actually can't modify/write in the file system..

Comment: I have the same issue despite mounting rw, using ES Explorer and so on. Very frustrating - any updates?

Answer (score 2):

**For rooted device:**

Goto 
[ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)

1. From left Menu Enable Root Explorer
2. Click on the same row (Root Explorer) a pop-up list will occur.
3. Select Mount R/W > select RW for both root(/) and system (/system) path.
4. OK

NOW YOU CAN EVEN **REPLACE(OVERWRITE)** any /system/etc folder.

> Tested on My 4.4.2 OS

Enjoy !!!!